# Make one gsub call instead of five

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, gsub

How can I replace this:

```
lyrics = lyrics.gsub(/\n/,'').gsub(/^\{\"similar\": \[/, '').gsub(/\]\}$/, '').gsub(/^\{/, '').gsub(/\}$/, '')
```

to something shorter and one gsub call?

Comment: Give some subjects to test regexp - with all that gsub's it is a bit hard.

Comment: Like: {"similar": [...]}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can joint multiple regexes into one by using alternate symbol `|` and creating branches in regex. Pay attention to anchors like `^`, `$` and other, because if they appear in one branch, they only work for that branch, not whole regex

```
lyrics = lyrics.gsub(/\n|^\{\"similar\": \[|\]\}$|^\{|\}$/, '')
```

Comment: You can combine `\]\}$` and `\}$` and use this instead: `\]?\}$`.

Comment: Maybe, but I didn't think about what this regex matches. I just removed `/,'').gsub(/` and inserted `|` instead :-)